# How does one rotate an entire metapost figure?

Tags: metapost

I have a metapost figure that I generated using map data and I would like to rotate the whole image by a small number of degrees to make the major lines parallel to the bottom of the screen. Is there a way to do this? Rotated on each of the lines produces (pretty) garbage.

Comment: Please post a compilable code so we can help

Comment: In the meantime, you could wrap your entire result using `draw image(<your image>) rotated <your angle>`, but, anyway, it's easier to help with a MWE.

Answer (score 3):

To rotate the whole of the current picture, you could try putting this just before the `endfig;`

```
...
currentpicture := currentpicture rotated theta;
endfig;
```

Where `theta` is the degrees of rotation you want.

If you want to apply this to all figures in an input file, you could try customising `endfig` so that the rotation you want is in there. Plain Metapost provides a simple hook for this.  What you need to do is to update the `string` variable `extra_endfig`, like this

```
extra_endfig := "currentpicture := currentpicture rotated 21";
```

Then every following `endfig` will rotate the picture before shipping it to the output file.

Note that you need to use assignment `:=` here and not equation `=`, because you are updating variables, not equating them.